# Marker or circle does not work on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'd like to use Leaflet but markers and circles seems not working on my map.

My map is well on the document but marker and circle are hidden.

My code :

```
var map = L.map(document.querySelector('#map')).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'MYMAP',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'MYTOKEN'
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);

var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
  radius: 500
}).addTo(map);
```

**Loadding with RequireJS :**

```
define('Composite-Map', ['leaflet'], function() { /*my code*/ })
```

Comment: Any errors? What have you done to debug?

Comment: Could not reproduce with the provided code: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/GbjJ77Ifz20V1q1V

Comment: I used RequireJS to load Leadlet. Any suggestion about that ? See edit#1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to define `leaflet` as a module. But it's not a module. Use `require` instead of `define` and it will work:

```js
require(['https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js'], function() {
  var map = L.map(document.querySelector('#map')).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
console.log(0);
  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    attribution: 'MYMAP',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'MYTOKEN'
  }).addTo(map);

  var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);

  var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 500
  }).addTo(map);
})
```

```css
#map {height:100vh}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"/>

<div id="map"></div>
```